# Navigating to the home page

Tags: android

When running an application, when the home key is pressed the mobile home page comes to the front.
How can i do the same on click of a button named exit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android home screen is an activity and you can launch it like other activities, by using Intent with the ***android.intent.action.MAIN*** action and the ***android.intent.category.HOME*** category.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer.. you can call [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) to end the current activity (this will not kill your application).  However I think you should really consider your decision to include a type of "Exit" button in your application.  Please review the mechanics of android and some of the information regarding this behavior.

There is a [very nice answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238).